# Java: Get the type of a removable drive on Linux

Tags: java, linux, usb

I have a Java program that detects the removable usb devices in a Linux computer. Currently, I can successfully get the drive name and the capacity (total, used, & remaining space) but when I use FileSystemView to get the system type description, the result is always "null". I know that this works on Windows, but not on Linux or Mac. Is there a way to get the drive type on Linux?

Comment: Non-portably, to get the drive type you could read /proc/mounts as a text file and find the line corresponding to the path of your file.  To get more information you could invoke the `df` executable instead, which typically calls statfs(2) for each entry of /proc/mounts, and capture its output.

Comment: @Chris Stratton I had considered doing that as a last resort but I just wanted to check and see if there was another way to get the drive type. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: It would definitely be a workaround, sorry I don't know if there is a formal "java-ish" method as currently most of my exposure to Java is actually on Android where the runtime details are quite different.